# Best way to select only the composite keys from a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a table called products which has a composite key of LineId and SizeId.
I want to select only these values. But whenever I do that I always encounter an error.
For example:

```cs
    return _dbset.Select(x => new KeyValuePair(x.LineId, x.SizeId));
```

I get the error

> cannot create a constant value of type keyvaluepair 
>   only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

This happens even if I `.ToList()` it before selecting.
I've tried using a Dictionary but with it being a composite key it thinks there are duplicates.

I want it so when the query is created, it only asks for the keys and not any other fields as I need the query to be quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Linq projections with `Select` you can use an anonymous type, or a custom class with a default constructor and getter-setters. Given you want to return that data, then custom class. You cannot utilize constructors on classes since EF cannot translate that into SQL.

```
return _dbset.Select(x => new LineSizeKey { x.LineId, x.SizeId }).ToList();
```

where LineSizeKey is a POCO class with the two properties /w Getters & Setters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `KeyValuePair` instance as there is no parameterless constructor available. If you want to just return the composite key values then create a simple class to hold the ID and type and use this:

```
return _dbset.Select(x => new CompositeIdClass
{ LineId = x.LineId, SizeId = x.SizeId });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about going like

```
return _dbset.Select(x => new {LineId = x.LineId,SizeId = x.SizeId}).ToList();
```

This query will only select `LineId` and `SizeId` Columns and you will get a `List<T>` where `T` is an `Anonymous Type` of `{int LineId,int SizeId}`

Answer (score 0):

You can select a Key Value Pair of composite columns. The Snippet below is to select the composite columns from a table .

```cs
return _dbset.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<decimal,decimal>(x.LineId, x.SizeId))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCVFW.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please note that it's not allowed to post personal details as name, email, address, etc... Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer